# Module `react-navigation-tabs` does not exist in the Haste module map

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I try to create a tab navigation in react native. But when I want to import `import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';`. I have the following error : `` bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-navigation-tabs` from `/Users/nicolasthibault/Desktop/RunApplication/Runenger/Views/NavigationReact.js`: Module `react-navigation-tabs` does not exist in the Haste module map ``.

I tried many commands that I found to similar topic but any of them works in my situation.
For example, I tried these ones but it doesn't solve my problem.

`` 1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`. ``

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please show me your package file?
I think it is a fault as a library version.

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-alpha.3",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.9.3"
  }

Comment: Oh, when I read it, it seems that I don't have this module in my project ?

Comment: I just added the answer.

Comment: I fixed this bug like above the answer.  please let me know if it works.

Answer (score 7):

Install `react-navigation-tabs`:

```sh
yarn add react-navigation-tabs
```

Or

```sh
npm install react-navigation-tabs
```

Then run metro:

```sh
react-native start --reset-cache
```

Also make sure you've followed the instructions here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html

Comment: It seems to work when I tried in Android. But I think I did a wrong manipulation because I can't build on ios anymore. Before in ten secondes, the app launch. Now I wait since 10 minutes and nothing happen. Do you have an ideau why or how resolve that ? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Make sure to follow the instructions in getting started guide properly and double check.

Answer (score 4):

1) Install 'react-navigation-tabs' using either npm or yarn
2) Build your project using npm start --reset-cache, If you are using expo use expo r -c

It'll work.